Discord Bot can't edit its message (discord.js V14)
I'm trying to make a Discord TicTacToe bot that works just by having the bot authorized to your account. I'm using the module discord-gamecord to do this. The bot works fine if it's added to the server, however the issue comes when it's not and instead it's authorized to a user's account. When someone tries to accept/decline the duel the bot doesn't reply, and when I look at the console it crashes with an error. Here's my code:
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const { TicTacToe } = require('discord-gamecord');

const clientID = '';
const token = '';

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions
  ]
});

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  const { commandName } = interaction;

  if (commandName === 'tic-tac-toe') {
    const game = new TicTacToe({
      message: interaction,
      isSlashGame: true,
      opponent: interaction.options.getUser('opponent'),
      embed: {
        title: 'Tic Tac Toe',
        color: '#5865F2',
        footer: 'Have fun!',
      },
      emojis: {
        xButton: '❌',
        oButton: '⭕',
        blankButton: '➖',
      },
      mentionUser: true,
      timeoutTime: 60000,
      xButtonStyle: 'DANGER',
      oButtonStyle: 'PRIMARY',
      turnMessage: '{emoji} | It\'s now **{player}**\'s turn!',
      winMessage: '{emoji} | **{player}** won the Tic Tac Toe game!',
      tieMessage: 'The game ended in a tie!',
      timeoutMessage: 'The game went unfinished :(',
      playerOnlyMessage: 'Only {player} and {opponent} can use these buttons.'
    });

    game.startGame();
  }
});

client.login(token);

const commands = [
  {
    name: 'tic-tac-toe',
    description: 'Starts a game of tic tac toe!',
    type: 1,
    "contexts": [0, 2],
    "integration_types": [0, 1],
    options: [
      {
        name: 'opponent',
        description: 'The user to play against',
        type: 6,
        required: true,
      }
    ],
  }
];

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

    const data = await rest.put(
      Routes.applicationCommands(clientID),
      { body: commands },
    );

    console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error while registering commands: ', error);
  }
})();


And here's the error:
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Andy's Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:749
    if (!this.channel) return Promise.reject(new DiscordjsError(ErrorCodes.ChannelNotCached));
                                             ^

Error [ChannelNotCached]: Could not find the channel where this message came from in the cache!
    at Message.edit (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Andy's Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:749:46)
    at TicTacToe.TicTacToeGame (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Andy's Bot\node_modules\discord-gamecord\src\TicTacToe.js:96:15)
    at TicTacToe.startGame (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Andy's Bot\node_modules\discord-gamecord\src\TicTacToe.js:84:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ChannelNotCached'
}

Node.js v20.17.0

If anyone knows how to fix this please let me know 

It's possible that the only reason it fails is that the message isn't actually in cache, eg from a bot restart. This can be fixed by either first checking that the message is in cache or replacing the cache lookup with a fetch. Both of these require editing the node module sadly. It could also be that the bot doesn't have permission to view the message thus it not being in cache, I'm not sure what you mean by "authorized to a user's account"

By that I mean that there are 2 ways you can use a Discord Application. Either adding it to a server or authorizing it to your own account, like those Restorecord verification bots. Either way I will try that thx

The error happens because the bot can't find the message or channel in its cache, which can occur after a restart or if it doesn't have the right permissions. To fix this, you can:

Use "partials" so the bot can reload messages and channels even if they're not in the cache.
Make sure the bot has permissions to read messages and access channels.

Basically, the bot needs to access the message or channel again when it's not in memory.
